# UIScrollview not working with Storyboard

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, ios8, xcode6

Hello I'm trying to setup a scrollview in the storyboard and followed the following steps to do it:

1. add a scrollview to the root view.
2. pin zero spaces to all edges of super view.
3. add a UIView (contentView) to the above scrollview.
4. pin zero spaces to all edges of the scrollview add some widgets to
   contentView and change the height of the contentView to 2000.

I saw this solution is working on many tutorials I saw but not its not working on me. What am I doing wrong? I use swift.

Can someone explain step by step how do to set up a scrollview in the storyboard?

My constrains:
[image: constrains for scrollview]

Comment: I assume you want the `contentView` to be the same width of the main view? And I assume you added the leading/trailing constraints for `contentView` to the `UIScrollView`. The problem is that those constraints merely adjust the `contentSize` of the scroll view, not the size of the `contentView`. Bottom line, you have to add a constraint between that `contentView` and the `superview` of the `UIScrollView`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22772106/1271826.

Comment: i edited my question. I tried it with the constrains between the contentview and the mainview but still no result.

Comment: Yes the contentView should be the same as the mainView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's imagine a the following view hierarchy (note, looking at constraints in Interface Builder are easier if you give those views unique names in the "Document" section of the "Identity Inspector"):

[image]

To set that up, you'd add the following constraints in IB (I'm justing going to write it in VFL, because it's a very concise way of showing the constraints):

1. Obviously, define scroll view relative to its superview (the main view, in this example):

   ```
   H:|[scrollView]|
   V:|[scrollView]|
   ```
2. Define, `contentView` such that

   - It's width is the same as the main view (`==view`), and
   - The scroll view's `contentSize` will change to fit the size of the `contentView`. Per [TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html), the constraints between a scrollview and its subviews defines the `contentSize` of the scroll view, not the relative size of the subviews.

   Thus:

   ```
   H:|[contentView(==view)]|
   V:|[contentView]|
   ```
3. Define the layout for three labels such that they're offset within the `contentView`:

   ```
   H:|-[label1]-|
   H:|-[label2]-|
   H:|-[label3]-|
   ```
4. Rather than hardcoding the height of the `contentView` (and thus the `contentSize` of the scroll view, instead just define the label's relationship to the vertical height of the `contentView`, which (because of step 2, above), adjusts the vertical height of the `contentSize` of the scroll view:

   ```
   V:|-[label1]-[label2]-[label3]-|
   ```

This is all you need to do. I didn't hardcode any widths (the main view has a width automatically, and both the scroll view and, more importantly, the `contentView` define their widths related to that. But the label widths are inset from the `contentView`, and the `contentView` height (and thus the scroll view's `contentSize`) is inferred from the intrinsic height of the three labels.

The end result is constraints in IB that look like:

[image]

---

FYI, if you want to do some diagnostics, you can click on the view debug button while the app is running on the simulator:

[image]

You can see the view (and optionally the constraints) and make sure everything looks ok:

[image]

You can also look at the `_autolayoutTrace` via the `(lldb)` prompt:

```
(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]

UIWindow:0x7fbbb3617910
|   •UIView:0x7fbbb349a840
|   |   *UIScrollView:0x7fbbb3491c80
|   |   |   *UIView:0x7fbbb348e180
|   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7fbbb348e450'Label'
|   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7fbbb3490670'Label'
|   |   |   |   *UILabel:0x7fbbb3490a70'Label'
|   |   |   UIImageView:0x7fbbb34a3eb0
|   |   |   UIImageView:0x7fbbb34a3800
|   |   *_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbbb349a970
|   |   *_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbbb349b460
```

This confirms that there are no conflicting layouts and that there are no ambiguous layouts.